Single Crossing Property - Approach
I have the following problem, and want to learn how to proceed in a very precise and short manner to show the SSCP for $U(.)$ without the brute force approach. I wanted to ask for your help to find how to briefly show SSCP in this and similar settings when faced:

A risk-neutral monopoly firm sells insurance to a single, risk-averse consumer. The consumer has initial wealth of $w>0$ and faces a potential loss of size $L$ with chance $p$, where $0<L<w$ and $0<p<1$. The loss chance takes on one of two values, $p_1$ or $p_2$, where $0<p_1<p_2<1$. The consumer knows whether $p=p_1$ or $p=p_2$ but the firm does not. The firm believes that $p=p_2$ with probability $\lambda \in(0,1)$. Call a consumer with loss chance $p_i$ a type-i consumer.
The consumer has expected utility preferences represented by a strictly concave vN-M utility $u$, which is $C^1$ with $u^{\prime}>0$ on its domain of $\mathbb{R}_{+}$. The firm offers the consumer a menu of contracts $\left\{\left(x_i, t_i\right)\right\}_{i \in\{1,2\}}$ where $t_i$ is the transfer that a type $i$ consumer pays to firm in both states of the world and $x_i$ is the money that the firm pays to a type $i$ consumer if the loss occurs, where the contract is constrained to satisfy $(0,0) \leq\left(x_i, t_i\right) \leq(L, w)$ for $i=1,2$. The firm's expected profit from a contract $\left(x_i, t_i\right)$ bought by a type- $i$ consumer is $t_i-p_i x_i$. Define a function $U$ by
$$
U(x, t, p)=p u(w-L+x-t)+(1-p) u(w-t)
$$
for $p \in\left\{p_1, p_2\right\}$ and $(0,0) \leq(x, t) \leq(L, w)$, the expected utility of a consumer with loss chance $p$ from a contract $(x, t)$.
The firm chooses a menu of contracts $\left\{\left(x_i, t_i\right)\right\}_{i \in\{1,2\}}$ to maximize expected profit subject to the "incentive compatibility" constraint that each consumer type $i$ weakly prefers $\left(x_i, t_i\right)$ to $\left(x_j, t_j\right), j \neq i$; and the "participation" constraint that each type weakly prefers its contract to the no-trade contract, $(0,0)$. The firm knows $w, L, p_1, p_2, \lambda$, and $u(\cdot)$ (but to repeat not which type the consumer is).

Does it follow from the given assumptions that $U$ satisfies the strict single crossing property (SSCP) in $p$ and $(x, t)$ on its domain? ${ }^1$ If so, prove it; if not add conditions so that it does and prove your assertion. No matter what, assume in what follows that $U$ satisfies the SSCP in $p$ and $(x, t)$.
